# Google Maps API - Radius search for markers using Places?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-places-api

I have set up a Google Map using API v3.  The map has a number of markers with infoboxes attached.  I am looking to set up a search box outside of the map for the user to input an address and then have the nearest markers returned based on the distance away (such as a radius search).

From the API documentation I think I need to uses the Places services.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 24):

To do a radius search with the API, use the [Geometry Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry) [google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical) method to calculate the distance between each marker and the geocoded result from the address.  If that distance is less than the requested radius, show the marker, else hide it.

code assumes:

1. array of google.maps.Markers called gmarkers
2. google.maps.Map object called map

   ```
   function codeAddress() {
     var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
     var radius = parseInt(document.getElementById('radius').value, 10)*1000;
     geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
       if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
         map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           map: map,
           position: results[0].geometry.location
         });
         if (circle) circle.setMap(null);
         circle = new google.maps.Circle({center:marker.getPosition(),
                                        radius: radius,
                                        fillOpacity: 0.35,
                                        fillColor: "#FF0000",
                                        map: map});
         var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
         for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length;i++) {
           if (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(gmarkers[i].getPosition(),marker.getPosition()) < radius) {
             bounds.extend(gmarkers[i].getPosition())
             gmarkers[i].setMap(map);
           } else {
             gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
           }
         }
         map.fitBounds(bounds);

       } else {
         alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
       }
     });
   }
   ```

[example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3_radiusSearch.html)