# how to calculate distance of an item from current location and show it in a text?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, street-address

I have to create a circle around a particular city on a google map so I came up with below code and it works fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}
h1, p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map_div{
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#outer {
    width:400px;
    height:50px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
#outer input[type="text"] {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

</style>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>

<div id="outer">
<input type="text" name="location" value="Current Location"><br>
<div id="map_div"></div>
</div>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", function () {
    myMap();
});

function myMap() {
    //add global geocoder
    window.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map_div");
  var mapOptions = { zoom: 10, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.808678, -117.918921) };
  window.map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas,mapOptions); 

  drawCircleAroundCity('ottawa');
}

function drawCircleAroundCity(cityName){
    if(!cityName) return;
  if(!window.geocoder) throw "Geocoder is not loaded";

  window.geocoder.geocode({ 'address': cityName }, function (results, status) {
    if (status == 'OK') {
      addCircle(results[0].geometry.location, true);
    } else {
      throw 'Unable to find address: ' + address;
    }
  });
}

function addCircle(position, recenter){
    if(typeof(position) != 'object') return;
  if(!window.map) throw "Map is not loaded";

  var myCity = new google.maps.Circle({
  center: position,
  radius: 50000,
  strokeColor: "#0000FF",
  strokeOpacity: 0.8,
  strokeWeight: 2,
  fillColor: "#0000FF",
  fillOpacity: 0.4
  });

  myCity.setMap(window.map);

  if(recenter)
    window.map.setCenter(position);
}
</script>
</html>
```

**Problem Statement:**

Now I have to find out distance of a particular item from current location and show it just above the `Current Location` textbox as shown in this below image. I have below item details in which there is an address of the item. Now can we use the full address of below item and calculate the distance from `Current Location` and show it above the textbox shown exactly in below image? For example `this is 187.51 km away from`. I am not sure what is the right way to do that.

Here is my working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4mtyu/10184/)

```
{
    "country": "canada",
    "state": "ontario",
    "city": "ottawa",
    "street": "riverside drive",
    "number": "1750",
    "postal": "k1g 3t6"
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use google map's distance API, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start